# vue 2 @click in child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have simple component

```
<template>
    <span @click="clickHandler" :class="className"></span>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "PlusIconComponent",
        props: {
            gender: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            part: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            opened: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: true
            }
        },
        data(){
            return {}
        },
        methods: {
            clickHandler(){
                console.log('clicked', this.part)
            }
        },
        computed: {
            className(){
                let classes = ['plus-icon', this.part, this.gender]
                if(this.opened){
                    classes.push('opened')
                }
                return classes.join(' ')                
            }
        }        

    }
</script>
```

This component is inside root component what depends on variable show different forms components (and use keep alive for them). 
In one of these component I use `PlusIconComponent` click handler doesn't work. When I move this event one components level up also it doesn't work.

This is weird because I used event in child before.

This component is display in a loop

```
<PlusIconComponent :key="part" v-for="part in parts" :part="part" :gender="gender" :opened="(showPart===part)" />
```

I also tested @click.native for the component but it doesn't work. Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `PlusIconComponent`, in your `clickHandler` method, you should emit some event to component's parent passaing arguments, like:

```
clickHandler(){
   this.$emit('clicked', this.part)
}
```

On the other hand, in your parent you should catch this event with another handler, which has the same name emited by the child:

```
<PlusIconComponent :key="part" v-for="part in parts" :part="part" :gender="gender" :opened="(showPart===part)" @clicked="parentsHandler" />
```

Finally, you can implement what you want in the parent:

```
parentsHandler(part) {
   console.log('parent says: ', part)
}
```

That is the way child component comunicates with its parents. More information [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

Comment: Thanks. Your way is correct to communicate between components parent-child. For me doesn't work click event on the span element in child component. Click event is in the same component what handler. It don't display console. It is impossible also to emit event to parent. My problem is don't detect click on span what is in child component, not communication between components and custom events. Of course I checked your solution, without effect

Comment: What is more interested, when I removed all from parent components and set just 2 divs. Event works on the main div in component and doesn't work for nested div `<div class="here-works main"><div class="here-not nested">Loren ispum</div></div>`